# Add node after rendered animation

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, compositing-nodes

I've rendered a long animation and was wondering if there is a way to get blender to import the animation image sequence and add the glare node to each frame. I don't want to spend another 13 hours rendering everything just to add the glare node in. And just blender let me at the node in after the renfer sequence is done will it look the same as if I had used the glare node in the beginning when I rendered the animation.

Comment: It depence on source files ... ussually Compositor is used for it.

Comment: I know that you use the compositor and add the node there so when you render it out then the glare is added. But I'm not able to spend as long as it took to render the animation the first time to do it all over again, so that why I was wondering if blender lets you import the image sequence and it's about to make the fog glow still.

Comment: That is what you can do in compositor ... add image sequence and add glare node so you dont have to render whole anim from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what you can do in compositor ... add **Image Sequence** node and add **Glare** node so you dont have to render whole anim from scratch.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know there was an image sequence node. After that, how do I save it. Do I have to manually save each frame myself, or can I save them all at once?

Comment: Render it as ussually